# returning changes made in listener

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

```
private fun getMenuList(): List<MenuItem> {
    val items = mutableListOf<MenuItem>()
    FireBaseRefs.mFireStore.collection("menu").get().addOnSuccessListener {
        for (document in it.documents) {
            items.add(MenuItem(
                name = document.data?.get("name").toString(),
                category = document.data?.get("category").toString(),
                description = document.data?.get("description").toString(),
                image = document.data?.get("image").toString(),
                weight = document.data?.get("weight").toString(),
            ))
        }
    }
    return items
}
```

Items within body of addOnSuccessListener contains data, but outside of it contains nothing. How should i return values from Listener

Comment: I think you might be interested in this article, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `FireBaseRefs.mFireStore.collection("menu").get()...` is making a network request. You get called on the `.addOnSuccessListener {}` once the network request is done.

So what is happenning to you is that the function returns right after making the network call and returning the empty list.

The solution here is either to make the code **blocking** by using coroutines or similar if you already have that dependency *or* you can pass a callback from your function that is going to be invoked as soon as the network request is finished.

**Callback version**

```kotlin
private fun getMenuList(onData: () -> List<MenuItem>) {
    val items = mutableListOf<MenuItem>()
    FireBaseRefs.mFireStore.collection("menu").get().addOnSuccessListener {
        for (document in it.documents) {
            items.add(MenuItem(
                name = document.data?.get("name").toString(),
                category = document.data?.get("category").toString(),
                description = document.data?.get("description").toString(),
                image = document.data?.get("image").toString(),
                weight = document.data?.get("weight").toString(),
            ))
        }

        onData(items)
    }
    
    
}
```

**Coroutine blocking alternative**

```kotlin
private suspend fun getMenuList(): List<MenuItem> {
    val items = mutableListOf<MenuItem>()

    return suspendCoroutine<List<MenuItem>> { cont ->
         FireBaseRefs.mFireStore.collection("menu").get().addOnSuccessListener     {
            for (document in it.documents) {
                items.add(MenuItem(
                    name = document.data?.get("name").toString(),
                    category = document.data?.get("category").toString(),
                    description = document.data?.get("description").toString(),
                    image = document.data?.get("image").toString(),
                    weight = document.data?.get("weight").toString(),
                ))
            }

            cont.resumeWith(items)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You could just use `Task.await()` instead of re-implementing the same thing with `suspendCoroutine()`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the firebase SDK your alternative looks like a better fit for the OP